# Which generic networked volume should be used for self-host kubernetes cluster bootstrapped by kubeadm?

Tags: kubernetes, storage

NFS, cinder, cephfs, iscsi, flocker, glusterfs, quobyte, rbd, flexVolume, vsphere-Volume, photonPersistentDisk, scaleIO. There are so many network storage options for kubernetes volume types. Which one is best suit for self-host kubernetes cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the right tool for the job.

**NFS** is the simplest to use, in my opinion. Choose it if you don't have any special requirements.

**Cephfs**, **Glusterfs** fit well if you need a distributed, fault-tolerant volume.

**ISCSI**, **Vsphere-Volume** are vendor dependent, you may want to use it if you have a piece of hardware which supports this type of storage.

Comment: Can you compare Glusterfs and Cephfs?

Comment: Here is the brief comparison: https://technologyadvice.com/blog/information-technology/ceph-vs-gluster/     https://www.networkcomputing.com/storage/gluster-vs-ceph-open-source-storage-goes-head-head/8824853